# how to check if getLogin() function worked or not to display login was successful or not

Tags: flutter, authentication, sqflite

I am not understanding how do i check if getLogin() function worked or not and if user exists or not.
where do i write the code to display the message. When I checked by assigning a variable to this statement

`res=dbService.getLogin(_email, _password);` then it shows datatype mismatch. Can u plzz help me with this. I am developing flutter app in android studio and using sqlite. Please do help me I am stuck from 2 days.

I call _submit() on login button

```
bool validateAndSave() {

    final form = _formKey.currentState;
    if (form.validate()) {
      form.save();
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
void _submit(){

    if (validateAndSave()) {
      setState(() {
        dbService.getLogin(_email, _password);
      });
    }
  }
```

And this is db_service.dart code for getLogin()

```
Future<RegisterUser> getLogin(String user, String password) async {
    await DB.init();
    var res = await DB.rawQuery("userDetails WHERE emailId = '$user' and password = '$password'");

    if (res.length > 0) {
      return RegisterUser.fromMap(res.first);
    }

    return null;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wait for the result of the login method.

```
void _submit() async {
  if (validateAndSave()) {
    var user = await dbService.getLogin(_email, _password);
    if (user != null) {
      Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/home');
    } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text("Sign in error")));
    }
  }
}
```

In this case I pushed to the home screen if successfull and showed a snackbar in case of error. You could adjust this to your intended use case.

Comment: The comment says to avoid thanks but I couldnt stay without saying thank u so much It helped a lot. problem solved.

Comment: Hi @FathimaShafana, you're welcome and glad I could help. Please if this answer did solve your issue mark it as solved.

Comment: Yeah I did it now. Sorry I didnt know dat. I am new.